# Lines are missing while convert XML to String

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I'm Converting XML to String using XMLDocument. my original file line count is 1150 but after converting if i check the string it shows only 710 lines only. and middle of the string it should be like

```
<LEV..._ATTRIB NAME="BULK_EXPENSED" VALUE="N"/>
```

but the original one is like

```
<LEVEL>PART</LEVEL>
```

here almost 300+ lines are missing. using below code.

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
  xdoc.Load(@"D:\Sample.xml");
  string document =  xdoc.InnerXml;
```

and tried below code also

```
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\Sample.xml");
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(file);
```

how can i convert XML to String without missing the lines/Data ?

**Note**: Here i need complete XMl file into String with Nodes

Sample Original XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<COMP>
  <LEVEL>PART</LEVEL>
  <ID>150-012-037</ID>
  <DESC>XYZ</DESC>
  <QTY>0</QTY>
  <WO_PART>123456</WO_PART>
  <COMP_ATTRIBS>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample1" VALUE="0.0"/>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample2" VALUE="Y"/>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample3" VALUE="Y"/>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample4" VALUE="Y"/>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample5" VALUE="N"/>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample6" VALUE="N"/>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample7" VALUE="N"/>
    <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample8" VALUE="N"/>
  </COMP_ATTRIBS>
</COMP>
```

Sample Error XMl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<COMP>
  <LEV..._ATTRIB NAME="Sample1" VALUE="N"/>
  <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample2" VALUE="Y"/>
  <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample3" VALUE="Y"/>
  <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample4" VALUE="N"/>
  <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample5" VALUE="N"/>
  <COMP_ATTRIB NAME="Sample6" VALUE="Y"/>
  </COMP_ATTRIBS>
</COMP>
```

Comment: Please attach the xml file

Comment: Or rather, please include a minimal example. We don't need a huge file - but a minimal example that actually shows the problem... along with a bit more context about how you're viewing the output. Assuming the document is actually using UTF-8 (which most XML documents are) I suspect the problem isn't where you think it is. (Having said which, File.ReadAllText would be a simpler way of reading the file as a string.) Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Most likely the parsing of the XML file (the `Load()`) and parsing it back to string, the XML gets rearranged a bit. There are no strict rules telling that an XML tag should exist on a single line or not. So for instance, a tag with several attributes can occupy two lines in a file and after parsing, the parser rearranged the XML and put the whole tag on a single line. So I don't think you are missing line, but the complete file is just rearranged.

Comment: @JonSkeet i added sample XML.

Comment: That's not a [mcve] though. How have you seen that "sample error XML"? I simply don't believe that if you have a file with that original XML, and you load it with the code you've shown, you'll end up with that "error XML" as in the string. Something else is going on here, but we don't have enough context to help you.

Comment: Use OuterXml : xdoc.OuterXml